# ‘struct packet’ has no member named ‘token’

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, compilation

I can't find the problem in this struct declaration. For some reason, variable `token` does not exist.

**packet.h**:

```
struct packet
{
    unsigned seq_number;
    char *arg;
    unsigned msg_len;
    unsigned short error;
    unsigned long token;

    enum type
    {
        PING,
        LS,
        WRITE,
        READ,
        APPEND,
        REGISTER,
        DELETE
    } msg_type;
};

struct packet p_init(unsigned seq_number, const char *arg, enum type t);
void attach_token(unsigned long token, struct packet *restrict p);
const void *p_encode(struct packet p);
struct packet p_decode(const void *p);
void p_cleanup(struct packet p);
struct packet p_error(unsigned seq_number, const char *arg, enum type t, unsigned long token);
```

**packet.c**:

I only included the implementation of the first function.

```
#include "packet.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct packet p_init(unsigned seq_number, const char *arg, enum type t)
{
    struct packet p = {.seq_number = seq_number, .arg = malloc(strlen(arg) + 1),
                        .msg_len = strlen(arg), .msg_type = t, .error = 0, .token = 0};
    strcpy(p.arg, arg);
    return p;
}
```

**Error log**:

This is only the first error. There are several similar to this, but in other functions.

packet.c:8:77: error: ‘struct packet’ has no member named ‘token’

**Compilation**:

```
gcc -o master src/master.c  lib/comm.c  lib/packet.c  lib/interface.c  src/fs/fs.c  src/server_table.c src/server/file_exec.c  src/worker_admin.c -DDEBUG -DLOG  -Ilib -lpthread
```

Comment: Whats your compilation command? `gcc -Wall -Wextra -c packet.c` produces no errors and the same for clang.

Comment: I will add it to the question.

Comment: Compile one file at a time. If you have an inexplicable error, first run your source through `gcc -E` and verify that you are including files you think you are including.

Comment: It might be useful for you to post the full build log.  Where is packet.h in relation to packet.c, are you certain that the one being included is the one you have posted. add a `#warning` directive to verify that the header you think you are including is the one you think - or @n.'pronouns'm. `-E` suggestion.

Comment: packet.h is in the same file as packet.c, namely in /lib. I include it using -I lib, which should allow me to import it like `#include <packet.h>`. But exchanging `#include <packet.h>` with `#include "../lib/packet.h"` makes it work for some reason. Any ideas why using `-I` doesn't work?

EDIT:

I just realized it works because I switched to another computer... Weird.

Comment: It's possible that `#include <packet.h>` is including a different header, not your library header, because the angle brackets can have a different (implementation-defined) search sequence.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Please make this an answer for Martin to mark.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I checked, but that's not the problem. I forgot to mention that everything was working fine, until I added the field `token`.

Comment: You could generate a preprocessed file, then examine that to see what the `packet` struct is declared as, and where it is declared (from the `#line` directives).

Comment: Miracles generally don't happen. If you can see a member named `token` in `struct packet` but the compiler cannot, it means there are two different places where `struct packet` is defined, and the compiler sees the other one.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. How would that be possible? I only defined the struct once, and there is no standard library header with the same name. I also have not included any other external library in the project.

Comment: I don't have your computer so I cannot check for you. I have mentioned some tools you can use above.